# Closing a popup window in servlet and refreshing parent window

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am creating a web app using servlet which uses Facebook for authentication. So whenever user press log in button i open a new popup window where user enter Facebook log in credentials and then its redirected to a servlet. In servlet i extract the information of user logged in and create a session. After creating the session i want this popup to be closed and parent window should be refreshed to another location. To open popup i use the following script

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
```

I want to imitate same kind of mechanism which Facebook like box uses when you click like and you are not logged in.

Comment: that is not actually a servlet problem. That is basic use of javascript

Comment: This is the code i'm using to open popup in which i load the servlet. Now i want to close this popup from servlet.

Comment: you will close the popup from the client . The servlet has nothing to do with it. The servlet only outputs html code

Comment: i have loaded a servlet in that popup now after servlet has done its work i want to close the popup window and refresh the parent window. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the job is done in the popup window you should call refreshParent()

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
  window.close();
}

</script>
```

This will do the refreshing of parent plus the closing of the popup.

Dont forget that this code should be in you popup window and called only after all job is done in the popup

Comment: how can i call this function from within a servlet?

Comment: you can call it on popup onload(), or from a button on the popup, or from anywhere except from the servlet. As I told you before, the servlet outputs html code. Nothing else! Its the job of the browser to interpret that html code, do the rendering of the page and run any javascript functions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add this code to your servlet page and call the function on a button click?

```
<script language="javascript">
function closeWin() {
   window.close();
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="closeWin;" />
```

There may be a security pop up warning you the application is trying to close the window and do you accept.  The only way I know to avoid that is reference 'opener' which is the parent window and perhaps blur the pop up, then perhaps onFocus() for the opener page it calls a function to close child windows.

Comment: i don't want to close window on button press rather it should be done automatically.